# Reading from a file in android

Tags: android, file, android-file

In the following code:

```
fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile) );
bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
```

Printing buffer is giving some random value, instead of what is there in file. `buffersize` is properly calculating the size of the file.
Can you tell wat is going wrong?

Comment: May be you are reading wrong file. Please check file location and its content.

Comment: Show the rest of your code please, maxBufferSize, and how you actually print the buffer.

Comment: rest of code was fine, now I have tried another way and it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
 private void ReadFile(AssetManager manager, String sourceFileName,
        String destinationFileName) throws IOException {

    // Read file from AccessManager
    InputStream inputStream = manager.open(sourceFileName);
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(destinationFileName);
    Log.d("-->", "src: " + sourceFileName);
    Log.d("-->", "Des: " + destinationFileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[3072];
    int length;
    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {

        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);

    }

    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
    inputStream.close();

    outputStream = null;
    inputStream = null;
}
```